Sum of reciprocals of nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function
Let
$$G(s)=\prod(1-\frac s\rho)\\=1-\left(\sum\frac1\rho\right)s+...$$
and
$$G(s)=2\zeta(s)(s-1)\Gamma(\tfrac s2+1)\pi^{-\frac s2}$$
be the infinite product representation of Riemann zeta funtion. Then,
$$\sum\frac1\rho=-G'(0)=1+\frac\gamma 2-\ln2-\frac{\ln\pi}2\approx 0.023095$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
Is this result/calculation correct? Thanks.

yes the result is correct the more general result can be found at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html  formula $(4)$

@GevorgHmayakyan Thanks.

The sum is not absolutely convergent, so you have to be careful how you define its partial sums

Wikipedia says: the factors for a pair of zeros of the form ρ and 1 − ρ should be combined. But, I dont know the details. İs there a bound on the norm of the roots? Should we accept the Riemann hyphothesis? @Conrad

the result here is true in general regardless of RH - by general theory one knows that $\sum |\rho|^{-1-\epsilon}<\infty$ while for $\sum 1/\rho$ one can either combine $\rho$ with $1-\rho$ and get an absolutely convergent series or do a Cauchy type sum taking the partial sums up to height $N$ (in other words summing all the roots with imaginary part at most $N$)
